# Minus all doesn't work although minus works

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT jt.*
  FROM JSON_TABLE (
           TO_CLOB ('[{"A":1,"B":11},{"A":1,"B":11}]'),
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS (A VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.A', B VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.B'))
       AS jt
MINUS --all
SELECT jt.*
  FROM JSON_TABLE (
           TO_CLOB ('[{"A":1,"B":11},{"A":12,"B":111}]'),
           '$[*]'
           COLUMNS (A VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.A', B VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.B'))
       AS jt
```

the first query return this table

| A | B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 111 |

the second query return this table

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 12 | 111 |

with minus or minus all I should become this table

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |

that's what what I've got with minus but minus doesn't work
why?

[code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=467029c14c55538c51663e96e935e848)

Comment: It's working. Since the first query returned same result in both rows, both rows have been removed by "minus".

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur Ok, thanks. I will update the question. Do you know why minus all doesn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it with the help of row_number() window function.

Since in below query every A and B combination has unique row numbers only matching number of rows will be removed.

Query:

```
 select row_number()over(partition by A,B order by A,B)rn,A,B from (SELECT jt.*
   FROM JSON_TABLE (
            TO_CLOB ('[{"A":1,"B":11},{"A":1,"B":11}]'),
            '$[*]'
            COLUMNS (A VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.A', B VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.B'))
        AS jt)
 MINUS --all
 select row_number()over(partition by A,B order by A,B)rn,A,B from (SELECT jt.*
   FROM JSON_TABLE (
            TO_CLOB ('[{"A":1,"B":11},{"A":12,"B":111}]'),
            '$[*]'
            COLUMNS (A VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.A', B VARCHAR2 (200) PATH '$.B'))
        AS jt)
```

Output:

| RN | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 11 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=054581a61eacaeae6ac35099f42ee65b)*

Comment: Ok but why is there a minus all in the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF

Comment: Actually I don't know. Will try to read about it and let you know later.

Answer (score 2):

The `MINUS ALL` operator was introduced in Oracle 21c and that version does include it in the [Set Operators documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF).

Your [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=467029c14c55538c51663e96e935e848) is using Oracle 18c which does not have that feature and it is not in the [Oracle 18 Set Operators documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF) or the [Oracle 19 Set Operators documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Set-Operators.html#GUID-5CB549AF-5A4F-453E-B164-49CAC8F94CBF).

If you want to use `MINUS ALL` then upgrade to use Oracle 21.